# Abstract class as member in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, abstract-class, member

I am trying to hold a member of an abstract class in a concrete class using hibernate:

**Concete class Forum:**

```
public class CForum extends AForum {
@OneToOne (cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private APolicy _policy; // abstract class member
```

**Apolicy is defined as follows:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="POLICIES")
public abstract class APolicy {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected int id;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }   
}
```

APolicy has several concrete classes that extened it.
The problem is if I try to load from the database I recive the following error:

```
    Error performing load command : org.hibernate.InstantiationException: Cannot instantiate abstract class or interface:  : policy.APolicy
```

If I change the type of _policy in forum to hold a concrete Policy class then I can load properly, but then I lose the abstraction which allows me to change polices (change the implementation between forums).

Is there a way to keep the abstraction and still be able to load correctly form the database?

Comment: Probable duplicate of [Hibernate: InstantiationException: Cannot instantiate abstract class or interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502455/hibernate-instantiationexception-cannot-instantiate-abstract-class-or-interfa).

Comment: @dcsohl its not the same case and not the same question... (I read this answer before I asked the question)

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you see as the difference? Only difference I see is annotations vs XML config, which is easily workable.